# Injecting into an EXE

Tags: binary, code-injection, masm

I really want to inject my C++ program into another (compiled) program. The way I want to do this is changing the first part of bytes (where the program starts) to goto the binary of my program (pasted into an codecave for example) and when it is finished running to goto back where it went before the injected program started running.

Is this is even possible? and if it is, is it a good/smart idea todo so?

Are there other methods of doing so?

For example:
I wrote a program that will write the current time to a file and then terminates, so if i inject it to Internet Explorer and launch it, it will first write its current time to a file and then start Internet Explorer.

Comment: if it is for your own use only?

Comment: Stack overflow probably already has enough answers in it to build a simple nuclear device, we don't need a step by step guide on implementing trojan horses.

Comment: @riodoro1 i don't want a trojan horse. and if i did, i would just download a good one online and use that one.

Comment: @SagarV For now yes, but it would be fine if i could pass it to other friends if they want to view it too.

Comment: @WhiZTiM I guess i would use seach machines and/or ask a friend. It wouldnt be hard [EDIT]: But like i said, its not for a trojan or any other mallware. altho it might be an idea to learn from source code how they do it.

Comment: Some of us are a bit afraid that you might accidentally pass it on to other than your friends, and so a bit reluctant to help with this.

Comment: @BoPersson I get that you guys are cautious who you teach those things online (and i actually appriciate it). I agree i could do damage if i used it for bad purposes, but i dont. Imma do it the simple way and just program my program to execute and then launch the program (without injecting it) and put a shortcut to my own created program so that it still works. Thanks for your time tho, alto i might kinda wasted it (sorry for this post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, you should start reading the documentation for PE files, which you can download at [microsoft](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi2vIqI9aPSAhVIuRQKHfH1CWoQFggkMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F9%2Fc%2F5%2F9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a%2Fpecoff_v83.docx&usg=AFQjCNFk3YGopstM20cK7Z7Wbve4pNbuDA&sig2=W7UPUPF6jRNSWutZjh8KKQ).

Doing this takes a lot research and experimenting, which is beyond the scope of stackoverflow. You should also be aware that doing this depends heavily on the executable you try to patch. It may work with your version, but most likely not with another version. There are also techniques against this kind of attack. May be built into the executable as well as in the OS.

> Is it possible?

Yes. Of course, but it's not trivial.

> Is it smart?

Depends on what you do with it. Sometimes it may be the only way.